# Vectorizing code

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I dont quite get the vectorizing way of thinking of matlab, mostly due to the simple examples provided in the documentation, and i hope someone can help me understand it a little better.

So, what i'm trying to accomplish is to take a sample of NxN from a matrix of ncols x nrows x ielements and compute the average for each ielement and store the maximum of the averages. Using for loops, the code would look like this:

```
for x = 1+margin : nrows-margin
    for y = 1+margin : ncols-margin
        for i=1:ielem
           % take a NxN sample 
           sample = input_matrix(y-margin:y+margin,x-margin:x+margin,i)
           % compute the average of all elements
           result(i) = mean2(sample);
        end %for i
      % store the max of the computed averages
      output_matrix(y,x)=max(result);
      end %for y
  end %for x
```

can anyone do a good vectorization of this example of a situation ? T

Comment: You should probably look at the `conv2` or `filter2` functions.

Comment: I will, but is there any other way to vectorize this type of code withouth using functions like conv2 or filter2 and do it using more matrix indexing?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, vectorization is not as important as it once was, due to enhancements in compiling the code before it is ran, but it's still a very common practice and can lead to some enhancements. Older Matlab version executed one line at a time, which would leave a for loop much slower than a vectorized version of the same code.

The part of your matrix that could be vectorized is the inner more for loop. I'll show a simple example of what you are trying to do, I'll let you take the example and put it into your code.

```
input=randn(5,5,3);
max(mean(mean(input,1),2))
```

Basically, the inner two `mean` take the mean of the input array, and the outer `max` will find the maximum value over the range. If you want, you can break it out step by step, and see what it does. The `mean(input,1)` will take the mean over the first dimension, `mean(input,2)` over the second, etc. After the first two means are done, all that is left is a vector, which the max function will easily work. It should be noted that the size of the vector pre-max is [1 1 3], the dimensions are preserved when doing this operation.